# How to add value to same cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, vlookup

I frequently do stock audits in my store by scanning barcodes into Excel. I use the Vlookup() function to avoid data errors. At times, I scan the same barcode again and again, always adding just one more unit. For each scan, data is added in the next available row.

Instead I would like to have an alternate method where the barcode would be recognized as already scanned, and the Scan quantity (column K) would update automatically. See the attached image where cells A5 & A10 have the same barcode as do A4 & A11.

I would like, for example, to have A10 & A11 not be listed separately, but contribute to the Scan quantities for A4 and A5, the previously scanned items.

[image]

Comment: What is the trigger that gets activated everytime you scan the barcode? Is this a VBA script? How the rows are being written to your excel file? I can also see the formula in column J, it references an external file, what type of data does that file hold?

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish between data entry and reporting. The scan writes into a data entry sheet and correctly records each scanned bar code in its own row.

You can create a report on a different sheet where you show the data aggregated by bar code. This can be done with a pivot table or with formulas. Formulas will update immediately, pivot tables will need to be refreshed, but if you are using VBA to manage the bar code scan results, it should be pretty straightforward to implement either approach into your code.

Comment: Thanks A Lot Teylyn. With your valuable reply I got an idea how I can manage my data while doing my store audits.

Thanks a Lot Again